# Is there a way to convert stud.io files into LDD files?

Tags: design, compatibility, ldd, bricklink-studio

Is there a way to download stud.io files from Bricklink and convert them into a format that Lego Digital Designer understands?

Answer (score 5):

Yup.

- Both programs (*Stud.io* and *LEGO Digital Draw*) can read the *LDraw* extension (*.ldr).

Overview:

- I'm using *Windows 10*.
- I have NOT ungraded to the *Stud.io 2*, but I think it shouldn't matter
  in this case.
- In *Stud.io*, we will be exporting the file into the *.ldr format.
- In *LDD* we will be importing a *.ldr file to be readable in *LDD*.

The Method:

1. Download ".io" file from *BrickLink* to your *PC*.
2. Open in *Stud.io*. and export save as a .ldr file. 
   (File > Export As > Export As LDRAW...)
3. Open *LDD* and import file. (File > Import model) Here you will also have to toggle the file format, *.ldr, you wish to import.
4. Find your *.ldr file and get to modifying.

Know Annoyances: Ghost Switching 1x4 Bricks.  Tubeless vs. Tubes files.

The final leg is to order your model through *Bricklink* via *Stud.io*, but *Stud.io* can't recognize the default tubed version of this 1x4 Brick. So, you'll be saying to yourself, but I've never used this tubeless version in my build, so what gives?

Apparently, the conversion into the *LDraw* format changes tubes into tubeless. This is annoying becasue it's not immediately clear why you're not able to find sellers for 100% of your wanted pieces, not understanding that a switch happened early in the conversion process.

Just a heads up.  In *LDD* you could search for these 1x4 tubeless pieces, and manually switch them out to tubed then re-save the file, or just mentally note to add the proper amount of tubes pieces in *Bricklink*.  Either method is just as annoying as reading this brick of text...

See  ya!

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunatetely, I experienced many issues with that approach. First of all, LDD requests a licence for a "Vortex toolkit", which I don't have. After canceling that, the file does load, but quite some pieces are missing. And for some models, pieces end up positioned incorrectly. This makes LDraw unusable as an intermediate format, at least for the 2 random models I tested!

Comment: TLG no longer provide new parts for LDD. These won't be available in LDD if your LDraw model has recently released new parts.